# jQuery Expandable Collapsible Div Not Working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create a expandible div at the very bottom of the page of my test site http://witthotel.perfectlysimple.org/about/. The line that should expand is "Click Here To Display The Content"

The html code of the div is as follows:

```
<div id="footer-bottom">
    <p class="expand-one">
        <a href="#">Click Here To Display The Content</a> <img src="images/arrow.png" width="5" height="7" />
    </p>
    <div class="content-one">
        <p>This is the content</p>
        <p> that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following script in the header running:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.expand-one').click(function(){
    $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

As you can see, it's a wordpress site, so it should load jquery, so I left the reference out.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

I actually tried it with and without the reference, but the problem remained the same: when I click on the "Click Here To Display The Content", noıthing really happens.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your console says `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function ` which means you are NOT loading jQuery. In addition to that you are loading `custom.scripts.js` wrapped in `<script>` tags, that's not supposed to be that way.

Comment: in custom-scripts.js, remove `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Take the link off.  If you have a `click()` handler you don't need to wrap the text in `<a></a>`

Comment: Along with your jQuery woes described below, you're using the wrong method if you want to show that "hidden" text.  It's already present on the page, just the color is white.  Make it black and you're home free.  `slideToggle()` will actually hide it on the first click.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hüseyin and Deryck. Your suggestions helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have another jquery library and it is conflicting. Use your code like below:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.expand-one').click(function(){
        $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but the problem remains the same. I left your modified script there, in case you want to have a look now.

Comment: In your `custom-script.js` you need to delete first line. `<script type="text/javascript">` cannot put in js file. Remove that line and try again

Answer (score 0):

Because Wordpress's jQuery is in noConflict() mode so your code shoudl be :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.expand-one').click(function(){
    $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but the problem remains the same. I left your modified script there, in case you want to have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom script has an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

and jQuery is not loaded as well
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

fix those errors and you will be fine